# How to execute another program as modal?

Tags: delphi

This is my function that should execute a program as "modal".

```
function EditAndWait(const AFileName : string) : boolean;
var
  Info: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
  FillChar(Info, SizeOf(Info), 0);
  Info.cbSize := SizeOf(Info);
  Info.lpVerb := 'edit';
  Info.lpFile := PAnsiChar(AFileName);
  Info.nShow := SW_SHOW;
  Info.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  Result := ShellExecuteEx(@Info);
  if(Result) and (Info.hProcess <> 0) then 
  begin
    WaitForSingleObject(Info.hProcess, Infinite);
    CloseHandle(Info.hProcess);
  end;
end;
```

Inspired by the answer to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393696/how-to-check-if-an-handle-should-be-closed), I'm thinking about changing the function.
In particular, it seems that in some cases, no handle is returned by ShellExecuteEx.

> You are only returned a process handle if:
>
> 1. You included `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS`, and
> 2. The function call succeeded, and
> 3. The action was resolved by creating a new process.
>
> ...
>
> > The action was resolved by creating a new process.
>
> Well, it's entirely possible for a shell action to be resolved by
>   re-cycling an existing process. In which case you may not be returned
>   a process handle. And that puts the kibosh on your code because you
>   have nothing to wait on, never mind no handle to close. You'll just
>   have to accept that such scenarios are beyond you.

I'm wondering if there's a way to be assured that my application is "blocked" until the other program has been closed.

Comment: The quote you show pretty much rules out that possibility. If there is no process handle returned, there is nothing to wait modally on. Period.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, but I'm wondering if I can achieve that result using other functions or maybe a different approach.

Comment: there isn't one, because you don't know what `ShellExecuteEx()` ends up doing, so you don't know what constitutes an appropriate waitable action. Does it launch a new process? Does it invoke a DDE command? A Shell handler? A command interface? You don't know. It depends on the file extension registration. And those things can run asynchronously. So you can't wait if it doesn't give you something to wait on. Just move on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: It's clear. What if I use another function like CreateProcess? Will I have more control on the process or will I encounter the same problems?

Comment: What process will you create? Obviously you can create a new process that way but then the behaviour will change.

Comment: @ExDev you can try, **IF** you can find the appropriate EXE to create a new process for (see `FindExecutable()` and `AssocQueryString()`), **AND IF** you can find the correct command-line parameters to pass to it. But not all commands that can be run with `ShellExecute/Ex()` involve an EXE that can be run with `CreateProcess()` directly.

Comment: Does the program that you want to execute as modal has a window? Because if it does, you can set that window as modal, at startup. Problem solved.

Comment: @bogdan a window does not have a modal property so what you describe makes no sense at all

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry; I meant the modal property of a form :)

Comment: @Bogdan Delphi form's don't have a modal property either.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to lock application main form with DisableTaskWindows() and EnableTaskWindows();

```
var 
  Windowslist : pointer;

WindowsList := DisableTaskWindows(0);
try
  // Do something ...
finally
  EnableTaskWindows(WindowsList);
end;
```

Comment: You have not understood the question.